# Submit form depending on the data returned by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have a form with an ajax script.The Ajax calls a php file which returns data from an API,I want to abort the submit if the code returned from the php file is not the desired one.As it is the form gets the data from ajax and still submits no matter what the data returned.What am I missing?

```html
<form id="login" class="" action="http://someurl/login" method="post">
    <div class=""><input id="email" class="" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" /></div>
    <div class=""><input id="password" class="" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></div>
    <div class=""><button class="btn btn-primary custom-button" id="log" onclick="ajaxtest();" name="submit" type="submit">Login</button></div>
</form>
```

```
function ajaxtest() {

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
    if (email == '' || password == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            async: false,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {


                if (result.content == 'some number') {

                    $('#login').submit();
                } else {

                    throw new Error(result.content);
                }
            },

        });
    }
}
```

In httpfox I can see the POST data returned by ajax and it`s fine.

EDIT

```
<?php
$loginUrl="http://someapi/login?token=blah";

    $data = array("email" => $_POST['email'], "password" => sha1($_POST['password']));



$json = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json))
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$content =  curl_exec($ch);

$code= json_decode($content,true);
$code=$code['code'];

echo $code;

?>
```

Comment: You don't prevent the normal submit of the form, do you?

Comment: @k0pernikus Not very familiar with jquery,that`s why I asked.

Comment: can you replace throw new Error(result.content);  with return; and check?

Comment: what do you need this `$code=$code['code'];`?

Comment: why aren't you ajaxing directly to the api?

Comment: @madalinivascu I need 2 actions on one submit,get the data from the api and login in some other website and I`m more familiar with CURL than js.

Comment: what is the xhr response look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason none of the answers above worked for me,this is how I finally solved it

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#login").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
     var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false
    }).done(function(result) {
      $("#response").html(result);  
        if (result == 'code')  self.submit();
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('error');
    });
});

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default click trigger use e.preventDefault();

```
function ajaxtest(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password;
    if (email == '' || password == '') {
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    } else {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "login.php",
            async: false,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {


                if (result.content == 'some number') {

                    $('#login').submit();
                } else {

                    throw new Error(result.content);
                }
            },

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason the POST request to the php file doesnt appear anymore when I inspect the headers just the POST to the original action so it still redirects.

Comment: change the type of the button to button

Answer (score 1):

As far i understand your question ,

The data is coming back as the string representation of the JSON and you aren't converting it back to a JavaScript object.

`dataType:'json'` in your ajax call or you can use `JSON.parse(result)`;
In your success function.

Comment: Still redirects me no matter what.

Comment: do you use preventDefault there ??

Comment: I did use preventdefault

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are not preventing the form from submition. What you should do is register a callback for the 'submit' event on the form element itself

```
first remove ajaxtest() as inline script
```

then create a new form submittion function

```
function myLoginSubmit(){
     if(  $('#login').data('myLoginValidated')){
         // this should be after you ajax request 
         ///formElement.submit();
         return true ;
     }else(){
        // only prevents submition  if not validated
        ajaxtest(e);
        return false;
     }
}
```

now hook the form submition

```
$("#login").submit(function(){
     return myLoginSubmit()
});
```

lastly change

```
if (result.content == 'some number') {

                $('#login').submit();
            } else {

                throw new Error(result.content);
            }
```

to

```
if (result.content == 'some number') {
                // now you made sure its what you want, then submit the form
                // the form wont be prevented because we set third parameter to True
                 //myLoginSubmit( null ,  $('#login') , true )
                   $('#login').data('myLoginValidated' , true);
                  return  $('#login').submit();
            } else {

                throw new Error(result.content);
            }
```

Comment: Alright,Iremove the function call in my form and edited a small typo after else in your code.Here is my new code in a single script http://paste.ofcode.org/6EtSpcGiXFUr9qWmYip6Dc but the POST header to ligin.php doesnt appear at all now,like ajaxtest is never called.Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, i saw a typo in the code check definition of myLoginSubmit() , the third parameter supposed to be validated and not validate. will try the code myself too, i have a chance now.

Comment: update: I have tested the code myself and i have completely rewritten my answer. You will notice the sections i cancelled out. Also ,there is no need calling e.preventDefault() because if the function returns False , the form wont submit.

Comment: I`ll test it a bit later and let you know,thanks. @Wakeel